# Using paging in UITableViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, uiscrollview

I have a UITableViewController that looks like this:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/dy6o55qa8squi9f/Screen%20Shot%202015-04-14%20at%2000.13.29.png?dl=0

And i want to implement a paging system by using UIScrollView. Now from what i understood UITableView inherits from UIScrollView. Still i have no clue how to proceed to make this happen.

So what i want to be able to do is when the users enters the view i showed on the picture the user can swipe to get to another UITableView with different data of course.

I tried myself using gestures for a while but i learned that i should not use it and use this method instead. I have been trying out this for a while to but i am getting nowhere.

Some guidance or code snippets would be of great help!

I am using storyboards.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you want to page vertically up and down within the table view, set `pagingEnabled` to `YES` on it and set its `contentSize`. That might get to be an issue if you start having rows that don't line up with the `contentSize` perfectly though.

If you want to page horizontally between different table views, you need to put each table view into a `UIScrollView`, set it's `contentSize` to be the width of each of the table views summed together, and set `pagingEnabled` to yes on it.

Comment: So i should delete my prototype cell. Put an UIScrollView, THEN put my cell over the UIScrollView?

Comment: You wouldn't put cells in the scroll view, you'd put whole `UITableView`s into it. Again, it depends on what behavior you'd want exactly. Horizontal versus vertical paging could be implemented very differently.

Comment: It is horizontal i am after.

Comment: Would you have a good tutorial maybe on how to implement UIScrollView with UITableView? or could you explain a bit how it should be done when it is horizontal i need?